# Erro com conversão de unidades

Tags: java

Alguém pode me ajudar no que está dando errado nesse código?

```
public class Conversor {
    public static String getUnidades(long quantidade) {
        return getUnidades((float) quantidade);
    }

    public static String getUnidades(int quantidade) {
        return getUnidades((float) quantidade);
    }

    public static String getUnidades(float quantidade) {
        quantidade = quantidade / 1024 / 1024;
        return  quantidade>=1024? (quantidade>=1024*1024?(("%.2f", quantidade /1024/1024) + "TB"):(("%.2f", quantidade/1024) + "GB")):(("%.2f", quantidade) + "MB");

    }
}
```

Ele é um método para converter unidades!

Comment: Um exemplo de saída que você usa e o resultado esperado vs o resultado obtido ajuda.

Comment: Vou editar, obrigado pela dica
Ele é um método para converter unidades!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tá faltando o String.format() antes de cada "quantidade".

Aliás, excelente uso do if no return. Ficou um código bem dinâmico.

```
return  quantidade>=1024? (quantidade>=1024*1024?( String.format("%.2f", quantidade /1024/1024) + "TB"):(String.format("%.2f", quantidade/1024) + "GB")):(String.format("%.2f", quantidade) + "MB");
```